# apche mod_rewrite not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

When I use PT or L flag, my URL shortening is not working. It only works with R flag. R flag is for URL redirecting, but I need internal rewrite. I am using apache 2.2 on Linux. I have mode_rewrite.so and mod_proxy.so in my modules directory.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/dam 
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /content/dam/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What actually handles the response for these requests?

Comment: If I have understood your question correctly, 
Original URL: http://epgidvlbrd1033.epff.nam.com:15100/content/dam/parts/images/22787711_Primary.jpg

Shortened URL:
http://epgidvlbrd1033.epff.nam.com:15100/parts/images/22787711_Primary.jpg